# Cannot find `cargo` binary on Rust toolchain on Apple M1

Tags: rust, apple-m1, toolchain, rustup

I got this error when I override the `rustup` toolchain to use the `rust-toolchain` in the repo directory:

```
error: the 'cargo' binary, normally provided by the 'cargo' component, is not applicable to the '1.69.0-aarch64-apple-darwin' toolchain
```

The content of my `rustup show`:

```
❯ rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/myhome/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2022-11-04-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.67.0-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.67.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.67.1-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.68.0-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.69.0-aarch64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

1.69.0-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/Users/myhome/myrepo/rust-toolchain')
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
```

The rust-toolchain file:

```
1.69.0
```

My Mac:

[image]

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: Has this been sorted in the meantime? I've just had a somewhat similar toolchain corruption and what sorted it for me was a `rustup toolchain uninstall stable` and then a `rustup toolchain install stable`. Let me know if this is still ongoing.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try these commands:

```
rustup component remove cargo
rustup component add cargo
```

Reference: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2704

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `rustup component add cargo`

Comment: That is odd if cargo was not installed by rustup initially... is that a bug?